# How to authenticate via GoogleAuth without storing credentials in file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-authentication

As I was learning how to implement a feature to interact with Google Calendar via API, I ran across a tutorial that used the following method to authenticate using a `credentials.json` file:

```
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
```

[According to the documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googleauth/0.5.0/Google/Auth/ClientId#from_hash-class_method), we can also use `from_hash`. The problem is that, even taking the *exact same contents* from the `credentials.json` file and turning it into a hash doesn't work. See the following:

```
[6] pry(main)> creds
=> {:installed=>
  {:client_id=>"[redacted]",
   :project_id=>"myapp-232803",
   :auth_uri=>"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
   :token_uri=>"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
   :auth_provider_x509_cert_url=>"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
   :client_secret=>"[redacted]",
   :redirect_uris=>["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost"]}}
[7] pry(main)> client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_hash(creds)
RuntimeError: Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present.
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/googleauth-0.12.0/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:99:in `from_hash'
```

As you can see above, it's complaining that the top level property 'installed' or 'web' needs to be present, but it is according to the hash.

I am just trying to avoid storing any sensitive information in a file and, instead, using it in an environment variable since I'll be deploying the app.

Comment: maybe it's worth to stringify keys? https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googleauth/0.5.0/Google/Auth/ClientId#INSTALLED_APP-constant

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

```
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/googleauth-0.12.0/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb
def self.from_hash config
    raise "Hash can not be nil." if config.nil?
    raw_detail = config[INSTALLED_APP] || config[WEB_APP]
    raise MISSING_TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT_ERROR if raw_detail.nil?
    ClientId.new raw_detail[CLIENT_ID], raw_detail[CLIENT_SECRET]
end
```

I just simply changed the hash from `"key":"value"` to `"key" => "value"` and everything works perfectly fine. Not sure why this was necessary, however, but this did the trick.